# Schedule Docker image to be run periodically on AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

How do I schedule a docker image to be run periodically (hourly) using ECS and without having to use a continually running EC2 instance + cron? I have a docker image containing third party binaries and the python project.

The latter approach is not viable long-term as it's expensive for the instance to be running 24/7, while only being used for a small fraction of the day given invocation of the script only lasts ~3 minutes.

Comment: I am not clear on what is your question.

Comment: automate the docker login process

Comment: aws ecr get-login --no-include-email >> execute the response to login into docker.

Comment: @INVOKECloud I have hopefully made a more concise and understandable question at the beginning of my post (and moved the background information below it).

Comment: @BugHunter This command you've given to me was necessary to be able to push the built image to the ECR repository, so I'm not sure where you intend for me to use this. The error I've posted above was displayed under the task details under a previously run task within a cluster on the ECS dashboard.

Comment: @SeanPianka, may be your config file trying to fetch from ecr and docker token has been expired, so raising this error. 

are you using docker compose or something else? if yes, please add your compose file after without sensitive data.

Comment: @BugHunter I'm not using docker-compose, and I know what you're talking about with an expired Docker token (which is why I mentioned that I've used the command you've posted before), but I don't believe that's the issue since I'm able to properly push my built image to the existing ECR repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For AWS ECS cluster, it is recommended to have atleast 1 EC2 server running 24x7. Have you looked at AWS Fargate whether it can run your docker container?. Also AWS Batch?. If Fargate and AWS Batch are not possible then for your requirement, I would recommend something like this without ECS.

1. Build an EC2 AMI with pre-built docker and required softwares and libraries.
2. Have AWS Instance Scheduler to spin up a EC2 server every hour and as part of user data, start a docker container with image you mentioned.
   https://aws.amazon.com/answers/infrastructure-management/instance-scheduler/
3. If you know your task execution time maybe 5min. After 8 or 10min then bring server down with scheduler.

Above approach will blindly start a EC2 and stop it without knowing whether your python work is done successfully. We can still improve above with Lambda and CloudFormation templates combination. Let me know your thoughts :)

Comment: It's now possible to schedule task in FarGate, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908548/3620552

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's possible to schedule the launch directly in CloudWatch defining a rule, as explained in

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html

This solution is cleaner, because you will not need to worry about the execution time: once finished, the Task will just terminate and a new one will be spawned on the next cycle

Comment: Here Can you do what that is specified in the Question? In the Question, he needs to have a specified downtime with the way I understood the Question in order to cost reduction. It is basically like the AWS RDS instance scheduler where we keep a downtime according to working hours. I just tried your answer it is basically like running a command like a cron in the interval that we have given.